# Finding memory leak in windows CE OS

Tags: memory-leaks, windows-ce

I have 2 images of windows ce OS.
My application shows memory leak in one OS image and nothing in the other.
And i am convinced that the leak is from the OS after an extensive analysis.
Is there a way to find the leak in the OS?
I have platform builder , app verifier tools.
And i tried with App verifier, it shows no leak from my application.
Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Do you have the BSP source, or is it a binary from a vendor?  If there really is a leak, most likely it's a problem in the display driver.

Comment: i have the source and to be specific only public files of WINCE...i can go ahead and debug...but i dont know the way to find...

Comment: I seriously doubt it a bug in the OS code, it's a bug in the BSP code, most likely in the video driver.  Diff the driver code between the leaking and non leaking BSPs.  You have all QFEs applied, right?

Comment: Yes. I did have all QFEs. In order deduce that it is a bug in the OS code, I came up with a small test application to reproduce the same. And it was accepted by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you can demonstrate the problem with an example program then either the supplier of your BSP or Microsoft are responsible for fixing this. I discovered a regression of network throughput due to the handling of TCP_NODELAY, and going the route of involving the vendor got the issues resolved.

You can of course post the code here to verify that it's correct and that it should not leak any resource. BTW: Which CE version and which programming language?

Comment: Thanks...i tried a test application which demonstrates this scenario(leak in one OS image and nothing in the other)..But my test app shows nothing in both the OS images...Its WINCE 6.0 and C++...My test app contains just a ListView created using CContainedWindow...I was concentrating on an example program, but could'nt reproduce the problem. So i thought, there must be a way to find leak with the source files which i have(Using BSP Source)

Comment: OK, without an example application this will be hard. Maybe you can start the other way around, remove things from your application until the problem goes away? Another way is to multiply operations, instead of clearing and filling the listbox once, clear and fill it ten times in a row. Another question: How exactly did you detect the leak? Is the OS leaking or just the application? What is it leaking, virtual memory, committed memory, GDI handles or something else?

Comment: My application has 2 screens with list views in both the screens. I will first load one screen and then next screen and then back to first screen and so on. When i keep switching screens i can see memory usage increasing after each load. This memory usage can be seen by running my own exe(It shows memory usage, allocated etc..) parallely...This is the scenario.. As described in my first post, i have two OS images...one with gesture support and one without(an old OS image)...

Comment: My application's memory usage increases in the OS image with gesture and nothing in the other(Since gesture can be observed in List View, i came to a conclusion that may be leak is happening from OS)

Comment: Do you have platform builder installed? If yes and adding or removing gesture support changes the leaky behaviour, I'd say that's enough to file a bug against Windows CE. However, wait: Google for "windows ce gesture memory leak" and you will find http://www.ptgsystems.com/blognet/post/2009/10/20/Touch-Gestures-and-the-Physics-Engine-in-Windows-Embedded-CE-60-R3.aspx, which seems to indicate that you must call CloseGestureInfoHandle() in some cases to avoid leaks. Maybe that is the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the link...I have made the necessary changes in code  according to the link and doing a long run test on the device..Will update soon.

Comment: In order deduce that it is a bug in the OS code, I came up with a small test application to reproduce the same. And it was accepted by Microsoft.